# Передача файлов формы с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть вот такой обработчик для формы. Проблема в том, что мне нужно прикреплять файлы и отправлять их вместе с письмом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить данный код таким образом, чтобы файлы тоже передавались.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       let form = $(".main-screen-form");
         $(form).submit(function (e) {      
               sendForm(this);
              $("form").trigger('reset');
               return false;     
              function sendForm(form) {
                  let formNm = $(form)
                  let formData = new FormData();
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'mail.php',
                    data: formNm.serialize(),

                    success: function (data) {
                        $(formNm).after(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                        $(formNm).after(error);
                    }
                });
              }    

          });
        });
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0_FormData

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/6138795